# List returns what it does not contain too

Tags: c#, .net, list, value-type

I have an image and Im adding some of it pixels in a list given below.

```
 List<Color> ycolo = new List<Color>();
 for (int p = 5; p < FilteredImage.Width; p++) { 
      for (int k = 5; k < FilteredImage.Height ;k++)
      {
          ycolo.Add(FilteredImage.GetPixel(p, k));

          if (k==10) { break; }
      }
    if (p== 20) { break; }
}


if (!ycolo.Contains(FilteredImage.GetPixel(21,11)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Im here");
}
else
{ MessageBox.Show("Im not here"); }
```

It returns `true(Im here)`, thoguh it does not contain the pixle at `21,11` position What is wrong here.Im working in Visual Studio c#.
What to do make it work?

Comment: Well, the pixel is not contained in the list but the color of the pixel may be included, maybe you are mixing up something?

Comment: @FlatEric I dont know im tottaly beginner any help here? like what type of list i should make?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to know, if the pixel at a position is contained in the list (independent of its color), you could use a list of `System.Drawing.Point`

Comment: Ok Ill initialize my list like `List<Point> ycolo = new List<Point>();`
But how do I add some element in it.
   `ycolo.add(?????)`

Comment: `ycolo.Add(new Point(p, k));`

Comment: Btw, you use the opposite condition - `(!ycolo.Contains` - *I'm here*

Comment: @IvanStoev my bad i cant edit it now

Comment: @FlatEric it sounds really help full but again in the if condition im having problem to check weather it exist or not?

Comment: check with `if (ycolo.Contains(new System.Drawing.Point(21,11))`

Comment: @FlatEric how do i mark ur answer as correct. It is really hellpful :)

Comment: I post it as answer, just a second ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the position and the color of a pixel.
The method `FilteredImage.GetPixel(21,11)` returns the color of the pixel.

To test if a pixel at a position was added to the list use this code:

```
List<System.Drawing.Point> ycolo = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();

for (int p = 5; p < FilteredImage.Width; p++)
{
    for (int k = 5; k < FilteredImage.Height; k++)
    {
        ycolo.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(p, k));

        if (k == 10) { break; }
    }
    if (p == 20) { break; }
}

if (ycolo.Contains(new System.Drawing.Point(21, 11)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Im here");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Im not here");
}
```

Comment: my reputation is not enough dammnnnn

Comment: I did it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

check your if statement.

```
if (!ycolo.Contains(FilteredImage.GetPixel(21,11)))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Im here");
}
```

there is **!** operator you are using so statement `ycolo.Contains(FilteredImage.GetPixel(21,11))` will return false but the ! operator will make the overall statement **true** and it will print "Im here" message.

Answer (score 0):

As a further improvement, I would suggest a little refactoring, due to 2 points:

- You have divided the `for` upper limits in 2 different places, for example for the width you've written `FilteredImage.Width` and `if (p == 5)`. The same for the Height. It is better to enclose a concept like "upper limit" in one place, unless you're algorithm is very articulated and needs that separation.
- "p" and "k" are not significant names for your variables, since your context deals with widths and heights, so instead use "w" and "h", or "x" and "y" (that automatically are seen as cartesian coordinates).

So, this is how I would write your code:

```
for (int w = 5; w < Math.Min(FilteredImage.Width, 20); w++)
{
    for (int h = 5; h < Math.Min(FilteredImage.Height, 10); h++)
    {
        ycolo.Add(new Point(w, h));
    }
}
```